# React router 5.0.0 is failing in webpack production build (Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom

I started a new pet project setting up webpack for react in order to understand the working of webpack better, my aim was to set up server side rendering and client rendering

while in **development mode is working** fine however in **production mode I get an error rendering the React element on server side**

**Invariant failed: You should not use Route outside a < Router >**

It must be something related to webpack optimizing the code , but i am not able to pin point it

React router 4.2.0 is working fine , however with react router 5.0.0 is not  working.
I tried other solutions like

- using only react router
- importing static router from react-router `import {StaticRouter} from "react-router"`

but nothing worked, I have set up a repo on github

https://github.com/RachitKalra/react-setup

Just install the node dependencies and run npm debug for development mode and npm start for production mode ( causing the error )

Thanks in advance, I am stuck here for a while now

```
Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
    at invariant (D:\Work\react-setup\node_modules\tiny-invariant\dist\tiny-invariant.cjs.js:13:11)
    at Object.children (D:\Work\react-setup\node_modules\react-router\cjs\react-router.js:454:21)
    at a.render (D:\Work\react-setup\www-start:310:64)
    at a.read (D:\Work\react-setup\www-start:307:58)
```